# Mixing structural and behavioral in VHDL, does it make sense?

Tags: vhdl, design

I've designed a VHDL unit, quite complicated, using a structural fashion, i.e. I designed the subcomponents and the interconnected them in the top unit.

Each of this component, including the top one, are implemented using combinatorial logic, i.e. there's no state machine in it.

Now I need to use this unit for a larger design, and basically for this design I would probably need a state machine (because I need some events to be timed). The only solution I then see is to used a mixed description (because state machines cannot be described without processes).

My question is, does this think of mixing designs descriptions make sense? I know I could do it, but I don't know it does make sense or not in general (i.e. if it is a common practice in the engineering community xD).

Just to give an idea of what I'm up to, it's something like the things below:
There are two new blocks, that I have to design as well. As you can see there's a feedback from the block I currently have implemented. That feedback I assume could need at least a register.

[image]

Comment: It's a common practice. If you have a hierarchical design, then it makes much sense to have the top level structural (mimic the block diagram) and implement the bottom levels as most convenient (but synthesizable). Just try not to mix the same module implementation styles..

Comment: What about if the top level block has sub-blocks with feedbacks? How can I make the top level only structural in that case? This is the case I have

Comment: Can you draw a block diagram of it? If you can, then you can make it structural.

Comment: How would make structural the stuff I have above?

Comment: It is already structural... Three blocks (modules) interconnected with wires.

Comment: I still don't understand... can you write down a pseudo vhdl? even with very simple logic.

Comment: I do agree for the wires, my issue is that at least one of those wires has to be connected to a register, and such register can only be implemented using a process, writing a process is not structural but behavioral. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is no register in the block diagram, right? Then it is probably internal to one of the blocks, i.e. is not a part of the top level.

Comment: I thought it was implicit when you draw feedbacks that a register has to be implemented... I mean given my question (but maybe it wasn't clear) you can assume that every block is implemented in combinatorial logic. Does the discussion change in such a case?

Comment: I don't see a reason for such a restriction. You *can* separate your blocks to sub-blocks implemented with combinatorial/sequential parts, but it doesn't change what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly normal to use structural elements to describe the higher level system while using behavioural elements to describe the individual parts of that system.

If you are planning to synthisize the design you will need to read up on what behavioural elements you can and can't use with your synthisis tool.